# Preserving Annotations in a mocked class for lookup using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, mocking, mockito

```
class SomeClass{

    @SomeAnnotation
    public void someMethod(){

    }
}
```

This is a class that I am mocking (to be precise syping) using Mockito and passing it to a part of my code that scans the instance of that class for some annotation for example `@SomeAnnotation`.

But I am unable to find the annotation on `someMethod` when I try to lookup for annotation using the spied instance that I am passing as a dependency to my class under test.

I know the reason that Mockito replaces the real instance behind a proxy and so I am unable to find it. But is there a solution for that?

Comment: use a real instance of that class to find the name of the method with the annotation and then use that to lookup the same method in the spied instance..

Comment: @redDevil the API is unaware of the presence of mocked instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not possible. Mockito guys are using CGLIB as a bytecode engine and the way they are using it does not allow annotation injection on methods (or anything for that matter) so unfortunately what you want to do is not possible with Mockito. I think there are several bugs/enhancements in their tracker about related things.

To overcome this - instead of using Mockito's spy maybe you could create your own? Like make a class that extends the class that you are spying now and somehow override the things that would cause problems in your test? Hard to give me more specific advice w/o seeing the class itself.

Comment: Yes I can do that, and presently using the same workaround. The tests would have been much better with mocks as I have to stub out many such cases :( Sadly cant wait for the feature. Thanks though.

Comment: Well don't want to be a party pooper but I was looking for something similar around 2011. I did a fast Google search on this topic just now but it seems nothing changed since then so I don't know if they will implement this any time soon. My guess would be that they might do it when they change the bytecode engine (probably not soon) and *after* changing it, which would take a long time...

Comment: Its 2021, has the engine changed. I am doubtfull :) hmm. Goto comment above.